# "connect" event not firing client-side socketio

Tags: javascript, sockets, websocket, socket.io, sinon

I am using `socketio` 1.0.4 version. Everything is working except the `connect` event on the client side is not firing.

client.js

```
//establish the connection with our NodeJS server
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
socket.on("connect", function(){
    console.log("connection made");
    socket.emit("room", {"room": "harness"});
});
socket.on('refresh', function (data) {
    //refresh the page
    console.log("Refreshing page");
    //document.location.reload(true);
});
```

server.js

```
var socketIO = require("socket.io")(server);
socketIO.on('connection', function(socket){
    logger.info("Connection to socket made:" + socket.id);
    socket.on("room", function(data){
        socket.join(data.room);
        console.log(this.id + " joined room - " + data.room);
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        logger.info("socket disconnected:" + this.id);
    });
});
```

I am using `express` on serverside. Everything is working fine on the server.

**UPDATE:**

I am using `sinonjs` to fake certain xmlhttprequest calls. but i am not faking socketio calls. I think `socketio` and `sinonjs` don't mix well.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure everything else is working correctly?

This part of code generates 'connected' on my 1.0.6 socket.io library

```
var socket  = io.connect();

socket.on('connect', function() {
    console.log('connected');
});
```

On the contrary socket.io does not have it's native refresh capability, so I do not know why do you claim that this fires on refresh of the page.

```
socket.on('refresh', function (data) { ... } )
```

Comment: I think i have figured out the issue. I am using `sinonjs` and i think it doest mix well with `socketio`. I am using fakeserver functionality of sinonjs.